# Parent and child onpress function

Tags: react-native, event-bubbling

I want one component should should accept onpress event from parent as well as child like below:

```js
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

function MyComponent(){
    testFunc1 = ()=>{
        alert("test");
    }

    testFunc2 = ()=>{
       alert("test");
    }

    return(
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.testFunc1}>
       <Button onPress={this.testFunc2} title="Call Test"  />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props of click action to the child

```
    import { TouchableOpacity,Text} from "react-native";
    Const childComponent=(props) =>{
     Const handleAction={
      props.clickAction();
      alert("child action")
    }
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleAction}> 
      <Text>touchableButton<Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
       ) 
       }
```

Comment: i have 2 different function. i have update my question.

Comment: Ok that mean u can call seperate function in your child with parent function as call back or else u want to load one means u can use conditions

Comment: i have parent compnent and child component both have onpress event. when click on child parent only called. child didnt called